# Htaccess maintenance page rules that actually work with WordPress?

Tags: htaccess, maintenance

I am trying to take my site offline for maintenance but only allow access to my IP address. However I can only ever manage to produce an internal server error. I don't understand how it exactly what i've done wrong. I want normal people to get my maintenance.php and for me to get the normal WordPress redirect rules and pages.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^maintenance\.php$ - [L] # Direct requests to maintenance.php should show file and stop
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC] # Give access to images on maintenance page
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx # My IP goes here
RewriteRule . /maintenance.php [R=302,L]

# Normal WordPress rules
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I've just asked - and answered - a similar kind of question myself here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/ It wasn't WordPress specific, but then, does it have to be?

Comment: You should put your rules in their own block. WordPress gets funny about sharing its space with others. I had to diagnose a client's site where their permalinks would not work. Once I moved their custom rules to a separate block, the permalinks started working again. Strange but true.

Comment: Looks like you're adding an extra slash in with your rewrite. Try adding `RewriteBase /` to the beginning of your rewrite rules, or changing the last line to `RewriteRule . maintenance.php [R=302,L]`. Otherwise, you're changing all your requests to **//maintenance.php**, a url that doesn't resolve anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

what about a plugin like maintenance mode?
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/maintenance-mode/

only allows access by logged in users